# Best way to render erb from database?

Tags: database, binding, ruby-on-rails-3.2, render, erb

I want to store my mail templates in erb format in my database.
In my templates i need access to basically the same helpers and instance vars that i have in my reqular file based templates in rails. So this is what i have in my mailer:

```
...
template = ERB.new(erb_from_db)
result = template.result(binding)
...
```

is rails passing the actual controller binding or exists there a better binding that i should pass to the template instead of the controller binding?

also i have read about `render_to_string` but it looks like its not the right thing for me but im not sure.

or do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: why not evaluate the erb and then store in db

Comment: whew, evaluated erbs doesn't sound like a good idea to me. e.g. If you use that mail template to notify subscribers to your newsletter. The moment you have it evaluated, you no longer need it in any possible way, not just in your db.

Comment: You should be fine using `ERB.new()`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2660808/rails-storing-erb-templates-in-database

Comment: ERB poses a major security threat: if your DB gets inserted with malicious data, an attacker could run ruby code on your app.
A safer solution would be to use plain HTML, and enrich it with your own tags, which you'll replace on runtime with proper values.

Comment: Hi @YossiShasho I have the same problem as Ali: I store templates of emails with some Ruby code. It can't really be inserted as the templates are created on an admin panel. Though can you elaborate on your technique of creating "own tags" ? Maybe a link to a tuto ?

Comment: @Maxence

Template: `Today is: {{RUBY_DATE}}`

Ruby code: `<%= $template.gsub(/{{RUBY_DATE}}/, Time.now.to_s %>`

Comment: Thank you. I think I will go that way!

Answer (score 0):

This works

```
<div class="ibox-content">
<% erb = ERB.new(@article.body.gsub!("&lt;","<").gsub!("&gt;",">")) rescue ERB.new(@article.body)%>
<%= render :inline => erb.result(binding), :layout => false%>
  </div>
```