# Allows user to edit pages that contain variables

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have some editable pages that are stored as text in my database. These pages will be called in my view like...

```
#app/views/static_pages/scheduling_text.html.erb
<%= Page.find_by_name("New Registration").content %>
```

Page.content is of type 'text' (not string). A portion of the text that contains variables would look like...

You have successfully registered for New Student Orientation on #{<%= @registration.orientation.class_date %>} at...

If course when I call this content in the view, I just get the text, not the model values. How can I make these pages access the model values? I also tried adding #{} around the text without success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, after much wailing and gnashing of teeth here is the the solution I cam up with. First I am using [mustache](http://mustache.github.io/). This is much safer than storing erb in the templates and prevents malicious injection of sql into your app. I simply added 'mustache' to my gemfile rather than mustache-rails as it seems to be more up to date. I then created a simple Page model with two attributes: :name and :content. I am using the page model to store the raw mustache code.

Here are the relevant files...

In my controller I call...

```
#app/controllers/registrations_controller.rb
def create
    @registration = Registration.new(params[:registration])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @registration.save
        if @registration.orientation != nil
          format.html { render "scheduling_text.html.erb" }
```

Then my view looks like...

```
#app/views/registrations/scheduling_text.html.erb
<%= Mustache.render(Page.find_by_name("New Registration").content, {:registration => @registration }).html_safe %>
<%= link_to 'Back', orientations_path %>
           ...
```

Then in my page model I have something like...

You have successfully registered for New Student Orientation on {{ registration.orientation.class_date }} at {{ registration.orientation.class_time}}. Please arrive 10 minutes prior to your scheduled Orientation. Remember, you must attend this Orientation session before you may register for classes.

...

Using a page model with scaffolding like this works well because it gives you the new, update, and create actions that will allow users to edit content. Note, they can easily mess up your ruby variables, so thats the downside. Just let your users know to not munk with anything that is between {{}}.

Hope this helps someone else out.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a duplicate of [Rails: storing erb templates in database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2660808/rails-storing-erb-templates-in-database)

Given that, this *should* do the trick for you, or at least be close enough to get you started:

```
<%= sanitize ERB.new(Page.find_by_name("New Registration").content).run %>
```

Additionally, you can remove the `sanitize` if content is not user-supplied (this is primarily a security concern).

I've done something exactly like this using HAML processing:

```
= sanitize Haml::Engine.new(article.content).render
```

For reference, here's the appropriate ERB documentation: http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/erb/rdoc/ERB.html

Comment: hmm...I'm getting the error undefined method `empty?' for #<ERB:0xb64bb5c>

Comment: I updated the answer to reflect the call to .run (you might also try .result instead of .run).  This should process the ERB code and return the result, which is what I think you want.

Comment: OK, thats better, but now I'm getting undefined method `orientation' for nil:NilClass. So it does not seem to be getting the assciation with the registrations. However, the plain code in my erb file works???

Comment: Are you defining @registration in your controller?  If so, it sounds like a variable scope issue (it's not being defined inside the call to ERB).  You might try an `eval` in front of the `Page.find_by_name`...

Comment: Yeah...now I'm wondering how the heck the other code even worked. I'm not setting any variables in my static pages controller.

Comment: I would suggest not using a variable in your content text, and instead call the model directly (if you're going to do it this way).

Comment: Wow! I can't believe this is this difficult. I must be approaching this the wrong well. I'm going to take breather and take a 2nd look at how I'm doing this architecturally. Thanks for the help Donovan.

Comment: OK, I got trashed on the other question I posted, so I'm back. :/ So I here is where I am at http://pastie.org/8550605 So now I do not get an error on the @registration code. However now just get a blank page. If I view source its just empty. Ideas?

Comment: Honestly, this is a classic case of swimming upstream, you're trying to do something that is a) not recommended and b) not the _rails way_.  Why are you storing variable assignments in your database and not simply using your controller and/or helper methods?

Comment: Exactly! Thats what I was trying to convey with my other question. Someone please tell me the rails way to do this. My only requirement is that the user be able to edit the content of the page (which will include varables). I am willing to refactor, I just need a nudge in the right direction.

Comment: I'll have to think about this... in the meantime, you should probably edit your question to make your intention clear (as you just did in the comment above).