# How to save HTML page in database?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, mysql2

How to save a HTML page in database using ruby?

I want to save several records in seed.rb `EmailEvent.create(email_event_id: 1, description:

> "contact_agent_notification", html_page:"html page goes here"`

I am not sure whether this is the right approach for this or not. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Looks good to me. What problems do you expect?

Answer (score 4):

1. You'll want the field in the database to be "text" instead of varchar, so it can hold all that html
2. You'll need to make sure that you add .html_safe to the field your views when you output the html directly. (e.g. `<%= email_event.html_page.html_safe %>` )
3. Security-wise, you definitely want to make sure that untrusted users aren't editing the HTML that's stored in the database. If not, you need to make sure you sanitize their input before you output it in a view.

As spickermann says, though, other than that things are pretty straightforward.

Comment: i have rails tag in html and i saved them but when i retrieve the html it should give me some name e.g "abc". it is now giving me something like this `Name: <%= @contact_agent.name %>`

Comment: @user2419697 So you're saving .html.erb files in the database, and want them to be processed before being output? Now you're getting really crazy. I just googled it, and this page looks helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2660808/rails-storing-erb-templates-in-database

Comment: Another option is to not store erb templates, but use backbone js or angularjs, which have their own templating engines. Then you could store those templates in the database and have them populated with javascript. It really depends on what you're doing.